# How to configure spring boot to return index.html from controller?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have following controller:

```
@Controller
class ReactAppController {
    @RequestMapping(value = ["/", "/{x:[\\w\\-]+}", "/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/**/{y:[\\w\\-]+}"])
    fun getIndex(): String {
        return "index"
    }
}
```

My expectations that it should return `index.html` file

It works if I put the file `index.html` under the `src/main/resources/templates`
And application have following dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

But I don't want to have

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

In my application because I don't use thymeleaf. But if I remove this dependency - I receive whiteble error page.

I believe that I have to configure viewResolver somehow but I can't find particular recipe.
Is there way to fix it ?

### P.S.

this doesn't work:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /templates/
      suffix: .html
```

although it looks correct:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I use to present a web page is:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public Resource homePage() {
    return new ClassPathResource("html/index.html");
  }
```

You don't have to have anything under a specific directory. Just specify your path when calling the ClassPathResource constructor.

Comment: what is the location of index.html ?

Comment: As long as it is on the resource folder, it can be whatever you want. Eg. mine is in resources/html/index.html